# How to unlock Nokogiri version on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nokogiri

I am trying to install the aws-sdk gem for Rails, but it requires a Nokogiri version less than 1.6.0.  I think due to a previous `bundle` install my system is locked on Nokogiri v1.6.6.2.

I tried removing the locked gem, and ran a `bundle update` but it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: When you say "I tried removing the locked gem", what do you mean? What did you do? We need to know the commands you used. What does "it didn't work" mean? How didn't it work? Specifics and being exact is very important. Please read "[ask]", especially the links at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 1):

Specify your desired Nokogiri version in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'nokogiri',  '< 1.6.0'
```

and run

```
bundle update nokogiri
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
gem uninstall nokogiri -v 1.6.6.2
```

then change the Gemfile to the version you want and then do a `bundle install`.